# Change CSS variable background image on Polymer app-header

Tags: css, polymer-1.0, web-component

I want to update the background image dynamically using CSS variables.

```
app-header {
    background-color: var(--paper-red-500);
    --app-header-background-front-layer: {
      background-image: url(var(--profile-cover));
    };
  }
```

But it won't update using this approach:

```
this.customStyle['--profile-cover'] = url;
this.updateStyles();
```

The app-header element is made from Polymer :)
Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

```
this.customStyle['--profile-cover'] = 'url(\'' + url + '\')'
```

So basically I have  to change the CSS:

```
background-image: var(--profile-cover);
```